# Django Form context data lost on validation fail

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My form (code below) loads and saves fine. However, if there is a validation error in the form and it is reloaded, the `context['uploaded_files']`  which I assign in the get_context_data method is empty. Why is that and how can I once again pass the `context['uploaded_files']` it when the form is reloaded on validation fail?

```
class BusinessEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'directory/business_edit.html'
    model = Appuser
    form_class = BusinessEditForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BusinessEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_object = context['appuser']
        files = [user_object.logo]
        context['uploaded_files'] = files
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BusinessEditForm(request.POST, instance=self.request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('directory/business_edit.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As per @Alasdair's suggestion, I amended the else clause as follows:

```
context = self.get_context_data()
return render_to_response('directory/business_edit.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It however, caused an exception as follows:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/h/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/h/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/h/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/h/Development/Pony/pony/directory/views.py" in post
  296.             context = self.get_context_data()
File "/Users/h/Development/Pony/pony/directory/views.py" in get_context_data
  272.         context = super(BusinessEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
File "/Users/h/.virtualenvs/pony/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_context_data
  100.         if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/business/edit/
Exception Value: 'BusinessEditView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by amending the else clause as follows:

```
user_object = self.request.user
files = [user_object.logo]
return render_to_response('directory/business_edit.html', {'form': form, 'uploaded_files': files}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As @Alasdair pointed out, it seems it is not a good idea to use class based views if you need any sort of custom behaviour. Probably best to use functions/methods from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included the context from `get_context_data` when you call `render_to_response`, therefore it is not included.

Overriding the `post` method of `UpdateView` isn't a great idea, because you have to duplicate all of the work that the base implementation does for post requests.

Try and override more specific things e.g. `form_valid` and `success_url`, instead of overriding the `post` method.

```
class BusinessEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'directory/business_edit.html'
    model = Appuser
    form_class = BusinessEditForm
    success_url = '/profile/' # ideally use reverse_lazy here
```

It is not clear what you want to do when the form is valid -- currently you are saving with `commit=False`, which means that the changes won't be saved the db -- so I can't offer any advice about how to override `form_valid`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The reason why I override post is that I manually add some relationships for uploaded photos which I removed from the code for this questions. Just one question - you say I need to include the data when I call render_to_response - how do I do that please?

Comment: You can get the context with `context=self.get_context_data()`, then pass that instead of the dict `{'form': form}` when you call `render_to_response`. But as I said, I wouldn't recommend that approach, try overriding something more specific than `post`.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair I'm new to python, and was wondering why you say you would not recommend that approach?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it means that you end up duplicating the functionality of the base implementation. CBV's are useful to avoid duplication and can be very quick to implement. However, the downside is that they can be trickier to understand. If you replace the entire `post` method of an `UpdateView`, then it isn't very similar to the original `UpdateView` any more, so it can take longer to work out what it's doing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion as follows:`context=self.get_context_data()
            return render_to_response('directory/business_edit.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`     However, this generates an exception: 'BusinessEditView' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: That's not enough information to see what's going on. Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks, I've included the trace back

Comment: You're getting that error because the `UpdateView` sets `self.object` in its [`post`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3f9dca62cb31a2b4b279b7d312a850660d21e91f/django/views/generic/edit.py#L277) method, but you have not.